# What is Pdfium Viewer and How do I install and run it in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, pdf

I like the pdf rendering in Google Chrome. It has smooth scrolling. So I searched and found 'PDFIUM VIEWER'. But all links are about compiling and source code and stuff. For the programmers I think.

I want simple exe file that can open pdf files.

[image: Pdfium Viewer]

How can I get it. Or do it..

Comment: I'm looking for font rendering like chrome (little deep dark kind) and smooth scrolling. Sumatra PDF, Adobe Reader, Foxit, PDF xchange, Nitro, Envice, none of them has that. And pdf rendering in firefox is nice too.

Answer (score 3):

PDFium viewer is an open-source PDF rendering engine for .NET apps. Many apps uses PDFium viewer to render PDF. It is not a standalone app.

You can try other alternatives like the one suggested by [Biswan](https://superuser.com/questions/1281513/what-is-pdfium-viewer-and-how-do-i-install-and-run-it-in-windows-10#comment1893286_1281513) or create your own PDF viewer using this [guide](https://code.google.com/p/pdfium/wiki/Build).